# MongoDB - How to update content to many collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a collection called "Image", below is 1 document of the Image collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6234342df8afb4001e279ecc"),
    "is_deleted" : false,
    "labels" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("623d687e745109001e09f146"),
            "labelId" : ObjectId("623d6821745109001e09f04e"),
            "xmin" : 0.400763358778626,
            "xmax" : 0.614503816793893,
            "ymin" : 0.694300518134715,
            "ymax" : 0.906735751295337
        }
    ],
    "img_name" : "6910486605301182464.jpg",
    "img_originalname" : "images (11).jpg",
    "img_desc" : "Cyber Sercurity multi upload",
    "img_uri" : "http://localhost:8080/resources/images/2022/3/18/6910486605301182464.jpg",
    "img_path" : "/resources/images/2022/3/18/6910486605301182464.jpg",
    "datasetId" : ObjectId("6234342df8afb4001e279eca"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-03-18T07:26:37.422Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-03-25T07:00:14.074Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

In this document, I have a field `img_uri` whose value currently starts with "http://localhost:8080". But now I want to find all documents with `img_uri`'s value is "http://localhost:8080" to replace with my domain `img_uri = "https://example.com"` and so the above document will look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6234342df8afb4001e279ecc"),
    "is_deleted" : false,
    "labels" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("623d687e745109001e09f146"),
            "labelId" : ObjectId("623d6821745109001e09f04e"),
            "xmin" : 0.400763358778626,
            "xmax" : 0.614503816793893,
            "ymin" : 0.694300518134715,
            "ymax" : 0.906735751295337
        }
    ],
    "img_name" : "6910486605301182464.jpg",
    "img_originalname" : "images (11).jpg",
    "img_desc" : "Cyber Sercurity multi upload",
    "img_uri" : "https://example.com/resources/images/2022/3/18/6910486605301182464.jpg",
    "img_path" : "/resources/images/2022/3/18/6910486605301182464.jpg",
    "datasetId" : ObjectId("6234342df8afb4001e279eca"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-03-18T07:26:37.422Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-03-25T07:00:14.074Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter - The document with `img_uri` starts with "http://localhost:8080" via `$regex`.

Work the update with aggregation pipeline, set the `img_uri` by replacing "http://localhost:8080" with "https://example.com" via [`$replaceOne`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceOne/).

With `{ multi: true }` to update all the filtered documents.

```
db.collection.update({
  "img_uri": {
    $regex: "^http://localhost:8080"
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "img_uri": {
        $replaceOne: {
          input: "$img_uri",
          find: "http://localhost:8080",
          replacement: "https://example.com"
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IRjtMLnGigc)

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by Yong Shun works fine for Mongodb version 4.4 and above, if you are using a lesser version, try this:

```
db.collection.update({
  "img_uri": {
    $regex: "^http://localhost:8080"
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "img_uri": {
        $concat: [
          "https://example.com",
          {
            $substrBytes: [
              "$img_uri",
              {
                $strLenBytes: "http://localhost:8080"
              },
              {
                $strLenBytes: "$img_uri"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Here's the playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Rm7YR5e0hoG).

Comment: Thanks you @Charchit Kapoor, it's also worked because I am using 4.4.3 version